# Google Maps V2 isn't working for me, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Ok, i've followed a tutorial on how to implement Google Maps V2 in Android, but im getting a "Class not found Exception" and of course the app crashes when opens.

Here's my Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.traincoders.transtracker"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.traincoders.transtracker.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.traincoders.transtracker.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.traincoders.transtracker.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="*** API KEY ***" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the simple layout that only has a fragment, according to what i read i should be using SupportMapFragment because of the backward compatibility, dunno if that's correct or not:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
   >

    <fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my Activity class, which extends to FragmentActivity:

```
package com.traincoders.transtracker;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);     

    }

}
```

This is how my workspace looks right now (with the libraries and stuff)

http://puu.sh/36dil.png

I've added the libraries as it should be by doing the following:

http://puu.sh/36dkw.png

And this is the stacktrace im getting:

http://puu.sh/36dmU.png

ADDING SOMETHING: Also, when i'm compiling, why do i have that WARNING icon before the target 4.1.2?

http://puu.sh/36egv.png

Comment: You might just didn't paste it here, but does the `MainActivity.java` file has `package com.traincoder.transtracker;` line on top?

Comment: Yes it has the package name sorry i didn't add it @Lablabla

Comment: If you change it to extend `Activity` and remove the `<fragment>` tag from the manifest, does it still give you the same error? (I'm not so familiar with fragments, just trying to rule out stuff)

Comment: @Lablabla yeah, without the <fragment> it works :( even tried adding an EditText just to be sure and yes. Looks like the fragment isn't correct, there might be something wrong with my libraries T_T

Answer (score 0):

As U wrote earlier You should use `SupportMapFragment`, for some reasons I had optically less problems with configurate `SupportMapFragment`.
You can also try to clean Your project and then Fix Project Properties by Android Tools. I have done it without LinearLayout, maybe it will help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<fragment
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/MapFragment"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Comment: No :( keep failing after what you suggested, did everything and nothing... this is the stacktrace still http://puu.sh/36i5r.png i've even added the google_services_lib in my /lib folder and reference the lib in the project from Properties. Also, if i add Google-API as the target, this little warning icon appears: http://puu.sh/36egv.png why is that? :S